# Aggregate additional values to min and max

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, datatypes, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-10

This is a follow-up question to:
[Make custom aggregate function easier to use (accept more input types without creating variants)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/214070/123371)

This SQL statement is given:

```
SELECT
    c.name AS commodity_name,
    c.category AS commodity_category,
    l.name AS location_name,
    min(b.price)::numeric(8, 3) AS min_price,
    valued_min(b.price, g.name) AS gameversion_of_min_price,
    max(b.price)::numeric(8, 3) AS max_price,
    valued_max(b.price, g.name) AS gameversion_of_max_price,
    avg(b.price)::numeric(8, 3) AS avg_price,
    count(b.price) AS price_measure_count
FROM buy AS b
JOIN location AS l ON l.id = b.location_id
JOIN commodity AS c ON c.id = b.commodity_id
JOIN gameversion AS g ON g.id = b.gameversion_id
GROUP BY l.name, c.name, c.category
ORDER BY c.name, l.name;
```

The custom aggregate functions from the previous question are used (`value_min()`, `value_max()`) plus `avg()` and `count()`.

Can that be written more efficiently? Maybe with window functions?

#### Desired result

Sample with first 18 rows

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.commodity
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('commodity_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    category character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT commodity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT commodity_name_key UNIQUE (name)
);
CREATE TABLE public.location
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('location_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    parent_location_id bigint,
    type character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    can_trade boolean,
    CONSTRAINT location_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT location_name_key UNIQUE (name),
    CONSTRAINT location_parent_location_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (parent_location_id)
        REFERENCES public.location (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
CREATE TABLE public.gameversion
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('gameversion_id_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT gameversion_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE public.buy
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('buy_id_seq'::regclass),
    location_id bigint NOT NULL,
    commodity_id bigint NOT NULL,
    price numeric NOT NULL,
    scantime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    gameversion_id bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT buy_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT buy_commodity_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (commodity_id)
        REFERENCES public.commodity (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT buy_location_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (location_id)
        REFERENCES public.location (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

Plain text:

```
"Agricium"  "Metal" "ArcCorp Mining Area 141"   "24.280"    "3.1.0-live.738964" "25.720"    "3.2.2-live.846694" "25.000"    "2"
"Agricium"  "Metal" "Grim HEX"  "25.000"    "3.1.0-live.738964" "36.490"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "30.983"    "6"
"Agricium"  "Metal" "Kudre Ore" "24.280"    "3.1.0-live.738964" "24.280"    "3.1.0-live.738964" "24.280"    "1"
"Agricium"  "Metal" "Levski"    "36.715"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "36.730"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "36.719"    "6"
"Agricium"  "Metal" "Port Olisar A" "0.751" "3.2.0-live.796019" "36.299"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "24.450"    "3"
"Agricium"  "Metal" "Port Olisar B" "36.229"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "36.300"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "36.276"    "3"
"Agricium"  "Metal" "Port Olisar C" "35.747"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "36.299"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "36.023"    "2"
"Agricium"  "Metal" "Port Olisar D" "36.299"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "36.300"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "36.300"    "2"
"Agricium"  "Metal" "Tram & Myers Mining"   "27.900"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "27.900"    "3.0.0-live.695052" "27.900"    "1"
"Agricultural Supply"   "Agricultural Supply"   "Hickes Research Outpost"   "0.728" "3.0.0-live.695052" "0.728" "3.0.0-live.695052" "0.728" "1"
"Agricultural Supply"   "Agricultural Supply"   "Levski"    "0.694" "3.1.0-live.738964" "0.722" "3.2.2-live.846694" "0.708" "2"
"Agricultural Supply"   "Agricultural Supply"   "Port Olisar A" "0.750" "3.2.2-live.846694" "2.025" "3.0.0-live.695052" "1.600" "3"
"Agricultural Supply"   "Agricultural Supply"   "Port Olisar B" "0.745" "3.1.0-live.738964" "2.025" "3.0.0-live.695052" "1.705" "4"
"Agricultural Supply"   "Agricultural Supply"   "Port Olisar C" "0.737" "3.1.0-live.738964" "2.025" "3.0.0-live.695052" "1.384" "4"
"Agricultural Supply"   "Agricultural Supply"   "Port Olisar D" "2.025" "3.0.0-live.695052" "2.025" "3.0.0-live.695052" "2.025" "2"
"Aluminum"  "Metal" "ArcCorp Mining Area 157"   "0.874" "3.0.0-live.695052" "0.875" "3.0.0-live.695052" "0.875" "2"
"Aluminum"  "Metal" "Grim HEX"  "1.149" "3.0.0-live.695052" "1.149" "3.0.0-live.695052" "1.149" "3"
"Aluminum"  "Metal" "Levski"    "1.143" "3.0.0-live.695052" "1.176" "3.2.2-live.846694" "1.153" "8"
```

Comment: You did not define which row to pick for equally lowest / highest prices per group. Also, grouping by *names* instead of unique IDs is potentially incorrect if names are not defined unique. And even if this is a follow-up, you still need to declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: Yes commodity, location and gameversion name-fields are all unique. Version is PostgreSQL 10.3, but this is a hobbyproject, I can use another database if this is needed ^^

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Unfortunately, I did not understand what you mean by 'row to pick for equally lowest / highest prices per group'. It was added the gameversion to the minimum price of the commodity and the gameversion to the maximum price of the commodity. And this for all locations.

Comment: Which row would you pick if two have the same minimum price for the same `(location_id, commodity_id)`? An arbitrary one?

Comment: Did not think about this state, currently I think it's arbitrary. I will test your answer when I'm back home from work, have a great day and thx for your greate help

Comment: Currently, it's an arbitrary pick. My query does the same. But that's typically undesirable: the same query can return different results on successive calls, without any changes to underlying data. There are [instructions how to fix in my linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, with window functions and without your custom aggregate function:

```
SELECT c.name     AS commodity_name
     , c.category AS commodity_category
     , l.name     AS location_name
     , b.min_price
     , gmin.name  AS gameversion_of_min_price
     , b.max_price
     , gmax.name  AS gameversion_of_max_price
     , b.avg_price
     , b.price_measure_count
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (location_id, commodity_id)
          location_id
        , commodity_id
        , first_value(price)          OVER w::numeric(8, 3) AS min_price
        , first_value(gameversion_id) OVER w AS gameversion_of_min_price

        , last_value(price)           OVER w::numeric(8, 3) AS max_price
        , last_value(gameversion_id)  OVER w AS gameversion_of_max_price

        , avg(price)                  OVER w::numeric(8, 3) AS avg_price
        , count(price)                OVER w                AS price_measure_count
   FROM   buy
   WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY location_id, commodity_id ORDER BY price
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
   ORDER  BY location_id, commodity_id
   ) b
JOIN   location    l ON l.id = b.location_id
JOIN   commodity   c ON c.id = b.commodity_id
JOIN   gameversion gmin ON gmin.id = b.gameversion_of_min_price
JOIN   gameversion gmax ON gmax.id = b.gameversion_of_max_price
ORDER  BY c.name, l.name;
```

Details might be optimized depending on exact table definitions (NOT NULL, PK,  FK constraints etc.) and requirements.

Related answer with more explanation:

- [PostgreSQL query with max and min date plus associated id per row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/postgresql-query-with-max-and-min-date-plus-associated-id-per-row/9800#9800)

Basics for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Potential performance optimization:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)